Using sqldf filter and group by in r dynamically
I am using SQLDF in r to select, filter and group by the data frame dynamically based on user inputs.
I have done the variable selection and done the aggregation part dynamically but not able to add the where clause/having clause in sqldf dynamically. User may select multiple combination of variable and their values as we well.
What I want is

since Texas in state and M in gender is selected so it needs to be shown only in the output on the fly. Had user selected any other combination then those combination will be shown in the output

Below is the code with the data
library(sqldf)

table_a <- data.frame(id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4),
                  state = c("Texas","Texas","Texas","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Nevada","Texas","Texas"),
                  gender = c("M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F"),
                  channel = c("Y","Y","H","Y","D","D","H","Y","Y"),
                  spend = c(10,10,5,20,20,5,7,1,2))



# user selects variable and their values  
# channel is not selected by user here
input_states <- 'Texas'
input_genders <- 'M'
input_channels <- NULL

a <- c('state','gender','channel')[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]
b <- paste(a, collapse = ",")

sqldf(sprintf("select %s,sum(spend) as tot_spend from table_a group by %s",b,b))

If-else may not be an option since there are multiple filter in my final application

Could you provide how your expected query shall look like? What does since Texas in state and M in gender is selected so it needs to be shown only in the output on the fly mean?

The final query will be like:  sqldf(sprintf("select %s,tot_spend from df where %s in ('%s')",b,c,d)). whatever the user inputs the final combination will be shown in the output

Okay, and what exactly is the Problem with ifelse()?

with few variables if -else will be okay but in my actual App there will be multiple variables and user can select any variable combination. Coding each combination will be difficult and prone to error as well

Can one assume that if there is a column in table_a, the corresponding input is always named input_[column]s? Also, aren't you overcomplicating things here using sqldf? Are you limited to this package?

input_[column]s is just a name . It can be any other name e.g. c or d , c <- 'Texas', d<- 'M" and then this will be used to subset the dataframe using     a <- c('state','gender','channel')[!is.null(c),!is.null(d),!is.null(input_channels)]. My actual app will be connected to HIVE tables in HDFS. SO need only SQL query to work with

You could build the where clause the same way as you build the select.
library(sqldf)

table_a <- data.frame(id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4),
                  state = c("Texas","Texas","Texas","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Nevada","Texas","Texas"),
                  gender = c("M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F"),
                  channel = c("Y","Y","H","Y","D","D","H","Y","Y"),
                  spend = c(10,10,5,20,20,5,7,1,2))



# user selects variable and their values  
# channel is not selected by user here
input_states <- 'Texas'
input_genders <- 'M'
input_channels <- NULL

a <- c('state','gender','channel')[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]
b <- paste(a, collapse = ",")

# Create the where conditions
where_conditions <- c(
    sprintf("state in ('%s')", paste(input_states, collapse = "', '")),
    sprintf("gender in ('%s')", paste(input_genders, collapse = "', '")),
    sprintf("channel in ('%s')", paste(input_channels, collapse = "', '"))
)[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]

# combine into where clause
where_clause <- paste(where_conditions, collapse = " and ")

sqldf(sprintf("select %s,sum(spend) as tot_spend from table_a where %s group by %s", b, where_clause, b))
#>   state gender tot_spend
#> 1 Texas      M        25

which I think is your requirement?
You can then control the output by changing the input_... variables.
# Try with different combinations of input_...
input_states <- c('Texas', 'Nevada')
input_genders <- NULL
input_channels <- 'H'

a <- c('state','gender','channel')[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]
b <- paste(a, collapse = ",")

# Create the where conditions
where_conditions <- c(
    sprintf("state in ('%s')", paste(input_states, collapse = "', '")),
    sprintf("gender in ('%s')", paste(input_genders, collapse = "', '")),
    sprintf("channel in ('%s')", paste(input_channels, collapse = "', '"))
)[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]

# combine into where clause
where_clause <- paste(where_conditions, collapse = " and ")

sqldf(sprintf("select %s,sum(spend) as tot_spend from table_a where %s group by %s", b, where_clause, b))
#>    state channel tot_spend
#> 1 Nevada       H         7
#> 2  Texas       H         5

Created on 2024-07-01 with reprex v2.1.0

This is indeed neat...Thanks a ton

Create a function cond which generates the text of one condition and create a list L of names and values removing those entries with NULL values.
Using that generate the where clause where and grouping variables groupby.
Finally use fn$ to enable text substitution (where dollar sign interpolates strings) and run the result.
The if at the end is to handle the situation where all the list variables are NULL.
Specify verbose=TRUE as an argument to f to see the final SQL statement generated.
library(sqldf)

# name is a character string, values is a character vector
cond <- function(name, values) {
  sprintf("%s in (%s)", name, toString(shQuote(values, "sh")))
}

# data is data frame, L is named list or NULL, verbose is logical
f <- function(data, L = NULL, verbose = FALSE) {

  L <- Filter(length, L) 
  sql <- if (length(L)) {
    where <- paste(Map(cond, names(L), L), collapse = ' and\n') 
    groupby <- toString(names(L))
    "select $groupby, sum(spend) as tot_spend 
      from data
      where $where
      group by $groupby"
  } else "select sum(spend) as tot_spend from data"
  fn$sqldf(sql, verbose = verbose)      
}

# tests
L <- list(state = input_states,
          gender = input_genders,
          channel =  input_channels)
f(table_a, L)
##   state gender tot_spend
## 1 Texas      M        25

f(table_a)
##   tot_spend
## 1        80


Something like this?
The 1st example is the question's example. The 2nd example has a where clause with the input_gender as filter.
Note the single quotes in s2. They are needed since input_gender is a character string.
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

table_a <- data.frame(id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4),
                      state = c("Texas","Texas","Texas","Alaska","Alaska","Alaska","Nevada","Texas","Texas"),
                      gender = c("M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F","F"),
                      channel = c("Y","Y","H","Y","D","D","H","Y","Y"),
                      spend = c(10,10,5,20,20,5,7,1,2))



# user selects variable and their values  
# channel is not selected by user here
input_states <- 'Texas'
input_genders <- 'M'
input_channels <- NULL

a <- c('state','gender','channel')[c(!is.null(input_states),!is.null(input_genders),!is.null(input_channels))]
b <- paste(a, collapse = ",")

s1 <- "select %s,
              sum(spend) as tot_spend
              from table_a
              group by %s"
query1 <- sprintf(s1, b, b)
sqldf(query1)
#>    state gender tot_spend
#> 1 Alaska      F        45
#> 2 Nevada      F         7
#> 3  Texas      F         3
#> 4  Texas      M        25


s2 <- "select %s,
              sum(spend) as tot_spend
              from table_a
              where gender = '%s'
              group by %s"
query2 <- sprintf(s2, b, input_genders, b)
sqldf(query2)
#>   state gender tot_spend
#> 1 Texas      M        25

Created on 2024-07-01 with reprex v2.1.0
In the 3rd example the where conditions are built from input_states and input_gender.
filter1 <- sprintf("state = '%s'", input_states)
filter2 <- sprintf("gender = '%s'", input_genders)
s3 <- "select %s, 
              sum(spend) as tot_spend 
              from table_a 
              where %s and %s
              group by %s"
query3 <- sprintf(s3, b, filter1, filter2, b)
sqldf(query3)
#>   state gender tot_spend
#> 1 Texas      M        25

Created on 2024-07-01 with reprex v2.1.0
